# Parse Cloud query error

Tags: javascript, cloud, parse-platform

I am trying to build a simple background job on the Parse Cloud. Right now, I'm just testing, but I am having a problem when performing a query.

If I comment out:

```
//query.ascending("createdAt");
```

the console log shows all the messages and no errors. If I don't comment it out, I get an error. Can anybody explain why this is happening? Is it an authentication error?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("cleanPosts", function(request, status) {

     var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
     var query = new Parse.Query(Post);

     query.ascending("createdAt");

     query.each(function(post) {
         console.log( "objectId:" + post.get("message") );
     }).then(function() {
         status.success("Success");
     }, function(error) {
         status.error();
     });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Parse.Query.each`, you do not need to (and cannot) provide an orderBy.  It will run the callback for every object (actually ordered by objectId).

The official error is `"Cannot iterate on a query with sort, skip, or limit."` and it should appear if you log that in the error block.

Comment: What if I want to limit the result to 40 element per page how to do it when using `each`